# WAR file generation error

Tags: jhipster

I have successfully completed the bookstore application and It's been running so far. I wanted to package the application in an WAR file and have it run of a different machine/environment.

Environment:
Windows 7
JDK 8
Maven 3.3.9
NodeJS 5.3

I run the following command
mvn -Pprod package

Issue #1 - Bower execution failed, resolved by updating git config for https:// instead of git://

Issue #2 -Python related errors - Do I need to setup Python?

```
C:\Source\jhipster-projects\bookstore1\node_modules\utf-8-validate>if not     defined npm_config_node_gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
```

Issue #3 - PhantomJS related errors, I did update PhantomJS still with the same errors

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 46 of 46 SUCCESS (34.659 secs /  1.536 secs)
←[1A←[2KPhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 46 of 46 SUCCESS (34.659  secs / 1.536 secs)
Missing error handler on `socket`.
TypeError: sockets.forEach is not a function
at disconnectBrowsers (C:\Source\jhipster-        projects\bookstore1\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:314:13)
at null.<anonymous> (C:\Source\jhipster-    projects\bookstore1\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:291:7)
at emitTwo (events.js:92:20)
at emit (events.js:172:7)
at emitRunCompleteIfAllBrowsersDone (C:\Source\jhipster-   projects\bookstore1\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:256:12)
at null.<anonymous> (C:\Source\jhipster-projects\bookstore1\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:278:9)
at emitTwo (events.js:92:20)
at emit (events.js:172:7)
at onComplete (C:\Source\jhipster-projects\bookstore1\node_modules\karma\lib\browser.js:142:13)
at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Source\jhipster-projects\bookstore1\node_modules\karma\lib\events.js:13:22)
at emitTwo (events.js:92:20)
at Socket.emit (events.js:172:7)
at Socket.onevent (C:\Source\jhipster-   projects\bookstore1\node_modules\socket.io\lib\socket.js:335:8)
at Socket.onpacket (C:\Source\jhipster- projects\bookstore1\node_modules\socket.io\lib\socket.js:295:12)
at Client.ondecoded (C:\Source\jhipster-projects\bookstore1\node_modules\socket.io\lib\client.js:193:14)
at Decoder.Emitter.emit (C:\Source\jhipster-projects\bookstore1\node_modules\component-emitter\index.js:134:20)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks that this issue has been resolved a few hours ago in Karma v0.13.19:

https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/releases/tag/v0.13.19

https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/2574

Comment: I have updated to Karma v0.13.19 and still the same error.  Also what I discovered is running the application using -Pprod resulted in the same error above.

Comment: Did you run `npm install` to update the node modules after updating `package.json`?

Comment: I  run npm install -g karma, is there anything I need to do before and after? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you fixed it already, but Chris's answer was right. The Karma module needs to be updated in package.json for your project since it specifies which exact version to use, and won't use the newer version that you installed globally.

Change

`"karma": "0.13.15",`

to

`"karma": "0.13.19",`

then, run npm install