# How to build a WAR file to deploy on Tomcat from a JHipster Spring Boot project?

Tags: maven, tomcat, spring-boot, jhipster

I created a project with JHipster, but made changes and added stuff to it. It runs ok when ran as a Spring Boot project from the IDE (Intellij), but when trying to build a WAR and deploy it on a Tomcat 7, it fails with the following stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/transaction/jta/JndiJtaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No JTA UserTransaction available - specify either 'userTransaction' or 'userTransactionName' or 'transactionManager' or 'transactionManagerName'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:543)
        ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No JTA UserTransaction available - specify either 'userTransaction' or 'userTransactionName' or 'transactionManager' or 'transactionManagerName'
        at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.checkUserTransactionAndTransactionManager(JtaTransactionManager.java:494)
        at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet(JtaTransactionManager.java:436)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
        ... 51 more
```

I also tried:

mvn -Pprod clean package

but that also fails with:

```
Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.35 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket gsod2iXnNubgdt_gVHUZ with id 68003640
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: google
  at C:/Dev/workspaces/myProject/src/main/webapp/scripts/components/view/geoChart.directive.js:9
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: google
  at C:/Dev/workspaces/myProject/src/main/webapp/scripts/components/view/geoChart.directive.js:9

PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (1.301 secs / 0 secs)

Warning: Task "karma:unit" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I have added the Google GeoChart, and that seems to cause an issue.

What I would like to get is a classic WAR that I can deploy on Tomcat, but I am obviously doing something wrong and I don't know what.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the *.war.original or the *.war?

I think you'd want to put the *.war.original in tomcat after renaming it to a .war file.

see the documentation: http://jhipster.github.io/production/

> To package the application as a "production" WAR, type:
>
> mvn -Pprod package
>
> Or when using Gradle:
>
> gradlew -Pprod bootRepackage
>
> This will generate two files (if your application is called
>   "jhipster"):
>
> target/jhipster-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
>   target/jhipster-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war.original The first one is an
>   executable WAR file (see next section to run it). It can also be
>   deployed on an application server, but as it includes the Tomcat
>   runtime libs, you will probably get some warnings, that's why we
>   recommend you use the second, ".original" file if you want to deploy
>   JHipster on an application server.
>
> Once you have deployed you WAR file on your application server:
>
> It will use by default the "dev" profile It can run in "production
>   mode" if you trigger the "prod" profile (there are several ways to
>   trigger a Spring profile, for example you can add
>   -Dspring.profiles.active=prod to your JAVA_OPTS when running your server)

Answer (score 0):

Also update the Karma version from `v0.12.35` to Karma `v0.13.19`.

That is, set `"karma": "0.13.19",` in `package.json` and rum `npm install`.
More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647017/war-file-generation-error).